# Add a subview to a UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITabController` and 3 `UIViewController`s, one for each of 3 tabs.

In one of these tabs, I want to add a subview (actually I want to replace the content of the tab with an other view.

This is what I'm doing:

```
QuestionClass *oView = [[QuestionClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuestionClass" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self presentModalViewController:oView animated:NO];
```

It works, but the tab bar is hidden, do you know you to show it?

Comment: check your UIView frame size.

Comment: it is possible to set a specific size ?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `presentModalViewController:` says:

*On iPhone and iPod touch devices, the view of modalViewController is always presented full screen. On iPad, the presentation depends on the value in the modalPresentationStyle property.*

If you're on an iPhone (iPod) and want your controller to stay within the tab controller's view space instead, you should look at having a navigation controller push it.

Comment: Or just add it as a subview sized to the full frame and brought to the front.

Comment: presentModalViewController: is deprecated anyway. Use presentViewController: instead and then you can define a presentation context, which could be limited to the current view's bounds. But still it's wrong what the poster is doing. UINavigationController is the way to go.

Comment: Ok I've done this

QuestionClass *oView = [[QuestionClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuestionClass" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.5
        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp 
        animations:^ { [self.view addSubview:oView.view]; }
        completion:nil];`

But now in the execution of QuestionClass, each time I call a method with [self XXX] I obtain a bad access. It seems that self is not QuestionClass ...

Comment: That's why the suggestions are to use a navigation controller.  Taking a view from one controller and stuffing it into a different view hierarchy causes problems if you don't keep a strong reference to the original controller.

Comment: do you mean a navigation controller in my second View of the UITabBarController ?

Comment: Put the view controller that has the content you want to replace inside a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use TabBar using Presenting view controller. TabBar uses to switch the views.

Comment: do you forget a word? tabbar uses XXX to switch ?

Answer (score 0):

One of possibilities would be:

Place navigationController as each tab (and corresponding viewControllers pushed for corresponding navigationController)

Then - in necessary tab You could push next ViewController, while TabBar is still visible (and in other tabs, information doesn't change).

Please see attached screenshot with NIB structure:

[image]